# Stop a python script without losing the experiment data

Tags: python

I used python to start an experiment last night, to test a C/C++ implementation of an algorithm.

The experiment data is printed to an exernal file like this:

```
f1=open('experiment.stats', 'w+')
f1.write(data)
```

I left it to run over night, and after ~10 hours it's 80% done. However I need to work and so I would like to stop the script from running.

Unfortunately if I press `ctrl + c` all the data will be lost. Is it possible to do something so that what ever python holds in the buffer at the moment gets flushed out to the external file?

Comment: Use nohup while starting the script, hit ctrl-Z type bg hit enter

Comment: the script has already started, is it possible to do something while it's running?

Comment: ctrl-Z and bg will push it to background

Comment: thank you so much... it worked!!! If you want add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I don't understand, were you only able to control the computer via a single terminal? You couldn't open any new windows or anything?

Comment: I could but I didn't want to spoil the experiment data by using other applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctrl-Z` and `bg` will push it to background